# $this->Model-id not set with CakePHP 1.3

Tags: cakephp, model

I am trying to retrieve the id of a record in my database in the index() method of my cns_controller.php file. I want to use it for a find(). However, the $this->Cn->id is not returning a value, therefore the find() doesn't work either.

```
$uses = array('Cn', 'Release');

/*check non-null value in released_user_id, 
 showing Release tab has been signed off*/
$releaseSignedOff = $this->Release->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Release.cn_id =' => $this->Cn->id,
                    'Release.released_user_id !=' => null)
));
(sizeof($releaseSignedOff) > 0) ? $releaseSignedOff = true : $releaseSignedOff = false;
$this->set('releaseSignedOff', $releaseSignedOff);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saving a record at some point to `$this->Cn`?  If not no ID to return.  Also, pretty sure should be `$uses = array('Cn', 'Release')`

Comment: No, what I'm doing at that point is gathering data to be pushed to the 'index' view.

Yes, it is an array in my code, just typed it wrongly above - fixed now.

Comment: My view() method works much the same as my index() method except it accepts a 'cn_id' parameter which I then use in the find(). Obviously, the index() does not have this parameter. :|

Comment: Ok, with Cake think of `$this->Model->id` as an alias for MySQL `last_insert_id()`.  This attribute only stores the ID of the last record saved.  If the ID you're trying to use is already saved in the `cns` db table then you need to call a `$this->Cn->find()` method to get the ID you're looking for.

Comment: Also, the 'view' and 'index' views look and operate the same way. Only difference being the 'index' view has the pagination feature. The reason both pages are built the same way is to make the user think they are on the same page even if they switch between in the 'view' and 'index' views.

The 'index' view is the landing page but as soon they interact with the site (saves, edits etc) they are redirected to that particular 'view' using the id as a parameter.

Comment: You are over-writing the result `$releasedSignedOff` with a boolean. Is this intended?

Comment: How are you hoping to pass this `$id` to the `index`? via the URL? What's wrong with using `view` instead, as is intended? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding but could you clarify?

Comment: @Ross Yes, that is intended because I'm only using the find to detect if there is a non-null value. I don't need the data, only a boolean if it there or not.

That's what I'm not sure about, passing the `$id` to the `index`. Well, it's because the system requires pagination between "records". So my `$paginate` array is limited to display 1 record at a time. However, I don't know how to recreate that on the `view` and redirect people to `view` when they login rather than the `index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using my `index` view, instead I looked up the most recent record in my `cns` database table and redirected to the `view` view using the returned value as a parameter:

```
if (!$id) {
    $most_recent_change_note = $this->Cn->find('first', array(
        'order' => array('Cn.id DESC')
    ));
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'cns', 
        'action' => 'view/'.$most_recent_change_note['Cn']['id']));
}
```

For the pagination, I ended up using the `$neighbors` feature of CakePHP:

```
function get_neighbors($id) {
    $neighbors = $this->Cn->find('neighbors', array('field' => 'id', 
        'value' => $id));
    $this->set('neighbors', $neighbors);
}
```

Then in my `view` view, I used those values to create links:

```
<div class="paging">
    <?php echo ($neighbors['next']) ? $html->link('<< Prev', 
         array('controller'=>'cns',
         'action'=>'view/'.$neighbors['next']['Cn']['id'])).' | ' : '<< Prev | ';
    echo $html->link('Next >>', array('controller'=>'cns', 
         'action'=>'view/'.$neighbors['prev']['Cn']['id'])); ?>
</div>
```

Thanks to Charles and Ross for helping me reach this conclusion. :)